# objective c - Efficient way to download an image from web and use it to show in image view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

in my app lets say there is 2 views ViewA and ViewB

in ViewA there are buttons for user to select option. And if he push one of them i will pull some images from web via web service and download them to the user's machine also i will put their paths to an array.

Then in ViewB i want to get images from that array and show them in image views

this is how i download images

```
-(void)startDownload
{
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr addObject:@"http://xxxx.com/Tulips.jpg"];
[arr addObject:@"http://xxxx.com/Koala.jpg"];
[arr addObject:@"http://xxxx.com/Penguins.jpg"];
for (int i=0; i<[arr count]; i++)   //download array have url links
{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:URL];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if([data length] > 0 && [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] isEqualToString:@"(null)"])
         {
             //make your image here from data.
             UIImage *imag = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
             NSArray *array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
             NSString *docDir = [array objectAtIndex:0];
             NSString *imgstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
             NSString *pngfilepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@sample%@.jpg",docDir,imgstr];
             NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imag)];
             [data1 writeToFile:pngfilepath atomically:YES];


             img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngfilepath]];

             NSLog(@"file is written");

         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] isEqualToString:@"(null)"])
         {
             NSLog(@"No Data!");
         }
         else if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
             NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
         }
     }];

}



}
```

when i run the app i see that file is written log is working so i think downloading the images is successful but i can't show image in imageview

you may think quiz up app on the store for understanding my problem clearly. quiz up first downloading questions' images then use them in another view. that's what i want exactly.

if my download code is correct how can i show them?

Comment: How are you trying to display the image? What do you do with the image view and when? Why are you creating a new queue on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: i found this code in web and first time i download images to app's folder so i am new to this subject. if you have better ideas please share with me and i can learn. this is how i try to show image img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngfilepath]];

Comment: Creating an image view is different to adding that image view to the screen. Have you searched `SDWebImage`?

Comment: is SDWebImage what i need? i will search it how can i use it in my problem

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView try this

Comment: why ur saving images in document directory...tell me first

Comment: @ercan- try my answer. and let me know any problem

Comment: @ercan check Third answer may be it will be help for u.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will allow you to download an image from the web, and does not require that the image be saved in the document directory:

```
 NSMutableArray *arry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [arry addObject:@"https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRr0WK-Q2t4Xxr1b6Kl7-lXdVEIh_Hj3HiDXk--Qg_0UAY0Y96P6w"];
 [arry addObject:@"https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRr0WK-Q2t4Xxr1b6Kl7-lXdVEIh_Hj3HiDXk--Qg_0UAY0Y96P6w"];
 [arry addObject:@"https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRr0WK-Q2t4Xxr1b6Kl7-lXdVEIh_Hj3HiDXk--Qg_0UAY0Y96P6w"];

 for (int i=0; i<[arry count]; i++)   //download array have url links
 {
    NSString *string=[arry objectAtIndex:i];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {
             UIImage *imagemain=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
             //         CGSize size=imagemain.size;
          //  UIImage *compimage=[appdel resizeImage:imagemain resizeSize:CGSizeMake(45,45)];
    //
    //         Cell.imgProfile.image=compimage;
    //         //         CGSize size1=compimage.size;
             imageView.image=imagemain;
         }];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you updating your UIImageView on the main thread, you can't update UI elements from a background thread. Try

```
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
            imageView.image = yourImage;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to cache the image. means the url will not be hit again and again.

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

-(void)startDownload
{
  NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [arr addObject:@"http://xxxx.com/Tulips.jpg"];
  [arr addObject:@"http://xxxx.com/Koala.jpg"];
  [arr addObject:@"http://xxxx.com/Penguins.jpg"];
     for (int i=0; i<[arry count]; i++)   //download array have url links
     {
        NSString *string=[arry objectAtIndex:i];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:string];

          SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
          [manager downloadWithURL:url progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize)
            {
                 // progression tracking code
             }completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
                {
                    if (image)
                           {
                  // here you can setup imageView frames and set the image on imageView
                          imageView.image=image;
                            }
                  }];
                        }
    }

   }
```

Comment: You may try http://github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage. It automatically caches UIImage/NSData on disk or in memory.

Comment: @slatvick- SD webImage is the industry standard even Facebook uses it